# Silence or disable Lenovo user experience spyware notifications without root

Tags: adb, tablet, lenovo, debloat

I am trying to disable "Lenovo User Experience" notification that pops up every ~4h. I linked some info below on the specific issue which is also probably illegal in the EU, but obviously the tech giants squish all the ants that speak up about it.

The apps with package names in question (not sure which one causes it):

- com.lenovo.tab_p11 (most likely)
- com.lenovo.lfs (maybe) named authentication
- com.tblenovo.whatsnewclient
- com.lenovo.productivity.service

**What I have tried so far:**

The tablet system is made in such a way that forces the user to use Lenovo services, no matter how many times the message is declined it comes up again.

As the app is a system app I cannot use the interface disable button (grayed out), this is not unusual and I had lots of success with adb on non-root devices like this. However it does not work. (I do not want to `adb shell pm uninstall --user 0` as that cannot be reverted without reset in case something breaks)

```
adb shell pm disable --user 0 com.lenovo.tab_p11

Exception occurred while executing 'disable':
java.lang.SecurityException: Shell cannot change component state for com.lenovo.tab_p11/null to 2
    at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.setEnabledSetting(PackageManagerService.java:21360)
    at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.setApplicationEnabledSetting(PackageManagerService.java:21161)
    at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.runSetEnabledSetting(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:2164)
    at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.onCommand(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:233)
    at android.os.BasicShellCommandHandler.exec(BasicShellCommandHandler.java:98)
    at android.os.ShellCommand.exec(ShellCommand.java:44)
    at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.onShellCommand(PackageManagerService.java:21982)
    at android.os.Binder.shellCommand(Binder.java:929)
    at android.os.Binder.onTransact(Binder.java:813)
    at android.content.pm.IPackageManager$Stub.onTransact(IPackageManager.java:4621)
    at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.onTransact(PackageManagerService.java:4459)
    at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1159)
    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:1123)
```

The notification settings are also blocked from the user for the spyware apps in question, so it is not even a matter of "shut up and take my data in the background".

I am sort of an android enthusiast when it comes to de-bloating android, fun adb automation and rooting, but in this case my hands are tied and my knowledge is not enough unfortunately.

**The exact answers I would be looking for are:** (tablet under warranty so no root!)

- Is there a way to force notifications off,
  I could not find an adb command for that.
- Other ways to try and disable the app

Here are some resources on the exact details of the issue:
https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Lenovo-Android-based-Tablets-and-Phablets/Lenovo-User-Experience-Program/m-p/5120621?page=1#5539399

https://www.reddit.com/r/Android/comments/b78wuj/the_bundled_nonremovable_virus_that_is_called/

Answer (score 1):

Same problem here. Unbelievable. Anyway. Using the simplest of tricks, this is how you can get rid of this annyoing bs *temporarily (using Lenovo Tab P11 (2nd gen) - Android 12):

1. Find and open settings.
2. Find and open System tab.
3. Become developer.
4. Find and open "Developer options".
5. Find and open "Running services".
6. Find and click on services umbrella named "Settings".
7. Find and stop service named "UserExperSuggestionService".
   [image: scr001]
8. Congratulations. The popup is now disabled (until you restart your device).